# Android camera2 ndk emulator

Tags: android, android-ndk

I do camera2 ndk google example, but it seems something goes wrongly:
in debug I get number_of cameras = 0, even if i have all permissions set.
This problems happenes on 24 and 26 version.
Might it happen because of emulator device?
Shall I somehow link libcamera2ndk.so to my application in graddle file? (I do link it in cmake and then i add this library to jniLibs folder )
it seems that the function ACameraManager_getCameraIdList is loaded and executed, because ACamera_Ok passed.

Screenshot attached. Thank you[image: debug screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Camera 2 couln't be emulated with android studio (at that time, I haven't checked with new android studio). To debug your applications you need a device with camera 2 support.